# Is it possible to disable f:event type="preRenderView" listener on postback?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, postback

Is it possible to "disable" triggering of this action when doing postback?

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{defaultNewQuestionHandler.init}" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's not possible with `<f:event>`. You need to manually check [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) inside the listener method.

```
public void init() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the upcoming JSF 2.2 `<f:viewAction>` tag, which is supposed to replace this `<f:event type="preRenderView">` "workaround", it will however be possible with the `onPostback` attribute:

```
<f:viewAction action="#{defaultNewQuestionHandler.init}" onPostback="false" />
```

Snapshot releases of JSF 2.2 are already [available](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html).

#### See also:

- [What's new in JSF 2.2?](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/)

Comment: @BalusC: On firing a POST, the listener method doesn't gets called for f-event. Any suggestions.

Comment: @Shirgill: I understand you basically want `<f:viewAction onPostback="true">`? Not sure how `<f:event>` is related to this.

Comment: @BalusC: What I dont understand is why the OP wants to disable the triggering of the listener method which, I checked is not getting c/d on POSTBACK?

Comment: @Shirgill: it still does in my sandbox project. Your problem is likely caused elsewhere and the cause is not visible in the information provided so far.

Comment: @BalusC: Got it. It will be c/d only if you don't navigate on POSTBACK, else the render response wont be executed for this particular view.