# JSF 2.0 URL parameter needed on larger scope

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have found a few good replies to similar content so far, but never something that solves my issue.  I am trying to accomplish this in the best manner possible.

Within my application (JSF 2.0 running on Glasshfish), I have a list of events (let's call this the EventPage).  It is possible to click on each event to then show a page of "results" (ResultPage), showing a list of people who have attended this event.

On the EventPage, the link is made as such :

```
 <h:link value="#{event.eventName}" outcome="displayResults">
     <f:param name="eventCode" value="#{event.eventCode}"/>
 </h:link>
```

Then, on the outcome - displayResult, I have code such as this in my backing bean (inspiried by a similar):

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DisplayResults {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.eventCode}")
...
```

This works well.  The results are displayed in a Datatable.  Now I want the ability to sort them.  So I've followed this example : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-sorting-example/.

But, once I change the scope of my backing bean to be something else the "request", I can't use the ManagedProperty anymore.  And thus am thinking I have to refer to something less elegant such as :

```
public String getPassedParameter() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    this.passedParameter = (String) facesContext.getExternalContext().
        getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    return this.passedParameter;
}
```

Aslo reading on this forum I share the opinion that if you have to dig down into the FacesContext, you are probably doing it wrong.

SO: 1. Is it possible to sort a Datatable without refreshing the view? Only the datatable in question? 2. Is there another good solution to get the url parameter (or use diffrent means)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<f:viewParam>` (and `<f:event>`) in the target view instead of `@ManagedProperty` (and `@PostConstruct`).

```html
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="eventCode" value="#{displayResults.eventCode}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{displayResults.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

As a bonus, this also allows for more declarative conversion and validation without the need to do it in the `@PostConstruct`.

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id)
- [Communication in JSF2 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)

Comment: This works fine for getting the url parameter.  But, I am getting another problem.  It is now during my init Function that I am doing my database access to fill values based on the parameter.  The issue is, when I come to sort data from DataTable, every request calls the init function, and therefore always getting new data from database, when really, I don't need to and have all the information needed in session scope.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Add a check on `FacesContext#isPostback()`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506033/is-it-possible-to-disable-fevent-type-prerenderview-listener-on-postback By the way, do you really need it to be in the session scope? Wouldn't view scope make more sense? The backing bean name `DisplayResults` doesn't seem to indicate that it represents the logged-in user or any of its session-related settings/preferences. You need to realize that a bean in the session scope is shared between multiple browser windows/tabs throughout the session.

Comment: Thanks! This is great help!  I have made changes to the scope of my page as well.  I had a session scope when things were not working - trying that, forgot to bring it back.  Thanks for the heads up!