# equivalent to restrict, action execute and navigation rule in page.xml (Java EE + JSF 2.0 - coming from Seam)

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, java-ee-6, restrictions

I learned building a web-app with Java and Seam (and JSF 1.2)

But now i'm working at the moment with pure Java EE 6 and JSF (Mojara 2.0.9) - without any extra Framework around.

In Seam i used for the `index.xhtml` the `index.page.xml`for restriction:

```
<restrict>#{authorizationManager.isAdmin()}</restrict>
```

Is there any equal function like the page.xml?

And:
I also used the `index.page.xml` to make some calls like:

```
<action execute="#{indexController.doSomething()}" on-postback="false"/>
```

Is it now the only chance to do it with an `@PostConstruct` in the Controller for the .xhtml?

Also how i'm doing something like this without the `page.xml`?

```
<navigation>
    <rule if-outcome="OK">
        <redirect view-id="/pages/index.xhtml" />
    </rule>
</navigation>
```

It seems to me, the pure JavaEE works totaly different?

(you don't have to send me full code, just give me the key words i have to google, thanks!)

Comment: Why did you expect that Java EE 6 has taken over all features of Seam? Why don't you just install Seam if you like its features?

Comment: i want to make an application which uses the standards, without seam..
i'm sure Java EE 6 has (hopefully) some equivalent features, or some best practise to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *In Seam i used for the index.xhtml the index.page.xmlfor restriction:*
>
> ```
> <restrict>#{authorizationManager.isAdmin()}</restrict>
> ```
>
> *Is there any equal function like the page.xml?*

Standard JSF does not offer any builtin authenticaiton/authorization facilities. All is to be used from the "raw" Servlet API or a 3rd party framework like Spring Security.

As to the "raw" Servlet API facilities, the `<security-constraint>` in `web.xml` comes close. You can only restrict on global URL patterns like `/app/*`, not on a per-page or maybe per-action basis.

---

> *I also used the index.page.xml to make some calls like:*
>
> ```
>  <action execute="#{indexController.doSomething()}" on-postback="false"/>
> ```
>
> *Is it now the only chance to do it with an @PostConstruct in the Controller for the .xhtml?*

The `<f:event>` in the XHTML page itself comes close:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{indexController.doSomething}" />
```

As to the `on-postback` replacement, check [Is it possible to disable f:event type="preRenderView" listener on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506033/is-it-possible-to-disable-fevent-type-prerenderview-listener-on-postback).

---

> *Also how i'm doing something like this without the page.xml?*
>
> ```
> <navigation>
>     <rule if-outcome="OK">
>         <redirect view-id="/pages/index.xhtml" />
>     </rule>
> </navigation>
> ```
>
> *It seems to me, the pure JavaEE works totaly different?*

JSF 2.0 supports implicit navigation which makes `<navigation-rule>` in `faces-config.xml` totally superfluous. The returned outcome will be implicitly treated as target view ID. You can perform a redirect by appending a `faces-redirect=true` parameter to the outcome query string. E.g.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "/pages/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)