# Phase listener to listen only if not a postback

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Basically, I need to call a method after RENDER_RESPONSE phase. I tried this:

```
<f:phaseListener type="com.examples.MyPhaseListener"/>
```

The above listener is listenening all the time even for ajax calls. I tried

```
rendered="#{!facesContext.postback}"
```

but its not applicable here I guess. So I tried this as mentioned in this post [Is it possible to disable f:event type="preRenderView" listener on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506033/is-it-possible-to-disable-fevent-type-prerenderview-listener-on-postback):

```
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent pe) {
 if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
          //do nothing
      }
}

public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent pe) {
      if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
           if (pe.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
               //call a method
            }
      }
}
```

It is working but is there any other way to disable the listener after the initial response?
I also tried preRenderComponent but it is called in before RENDER_RESPONSE phase and it looks like it is not rendering response until the method is out of the stack ( basically it is not asynchronous). So I feel there is not much advantage of SystemEvents like preRenderView and preRenderComponent when compared to calling them in PostConstruct.

Comment: "Not on ajax-requests" and "not on postback" are not the same, which one do you need? Also, what exactly do you mean by "asynchronous"? JSF is implemented as a servlet, and all JSF code assumes it will run in the request processing thread, so asynchronously interacting with JSF is not intended usage.

Comment: And what do you mean by "calling events in PostConstruct"?

Comment: Ajax requests are implicitly always postbacks. But not all postbacks are necessarily ajax requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really another way to achieve the functional requirement. A `Filter` wherein you do the job *after* the `chain.doFilter(request, response)` call should also work, but this doesn't give you access to the faces context (although a lot of JSF specific data is also available by the standard Servlet API).

As to your phase listener, if you need to get it to listen on render response *only*, then add

```
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}
```

This way you don't need to check the current phase in the listener methods.

```
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        // ...
   }
}
```

In the upcoming JSF 2.2 there will by the way be a new tag which understands `isPostback()`, the `<f:viewAction>`:

```
<f:viewAction action="#{bean.action}" onPostback="false" />
```

However, it runs during invoke action phase only.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will atleast use it to listen on render  response only and phase listener was a better option for me than a filter.

Comment: @BalusC you made JSF easy to deal with I'm following all your answers thanks so much ;)