# ui:include dependent on viewParam

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, viewparams

I have a page where I want to include a part of the page (footer in this instance) dependant on values given from a view parameter.

I have my `ViewScoped` backing bean initializing on preRenderView

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="racecode" value="#{displayResults.racecode}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{displayResults.init}" />  
</f:metadata>
```

This queries the database to get the name of the footer to be included.  This then, is used in this fashion :

```
<h:panelGroup id="customFooter" display="block">
    <ui:include src="#{displayResults.customFooter}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

This always gives me a missing page.  But if I enter the page name manually it works.  Same if I replace the `ui:include` with an `h:outputText`.

I understand that it has something to do with the phases of JSF and that at the time the `ui:include` is done, the value is not set yet. (reading up and better understanding the phases is something on my TODO list).

The question remains.  How can I get something of the sort done.  Have a bean use the viewParam, query the database and use that value in a `ui:include`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@wemu has already explained the cause. The `<ui:include src>` is evaluated before `init()` method is called. His proposed `<f:phaseListener>` solution is however clumsy.

Just use `@ManagedProperty`/`@PostConstruct` on a `@RequestScoped` bean.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.racecode}")
private String racecode;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This makes total sense.  I'm often concerned about best practices and stuff like this (OCD a bit I think).  Now let's say I am loading two beans for this one page load, and this creates an extra call to the databse.  Of course, I have the information I need to make this work.  Would it be better to change my current `preRenderView` completely to this and have all at one location?  Also, why `@RequestScoped` here?

Comment: You could inject beans in each other by [`@ManagedProperty`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther). The `@RequestScoped` is mandatory for 2 reasons: 1) the `#{param}` is request scoped 2) the `<ui:include>` is a [taghandler](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers). So `@ViewScope` is absolutely not an option.

Comment: This did work for what I wanted to do.  But seems to have let to another issue.  I have my resquest scope and view scope bean both on the same page.  When I trigger an actionListener on my page that is supposed to trigger a method in my viewScope bean, it only calls the request scope bean and never makes it to the method in question.

Comment: There are indeed prolems with regard to using forms in combination with dynamic includes. See this question+answer for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408130/jsf-commandbutton-works-on-second-click

Comment: Similar problem, but the solution did not work.  I now have the same `displayResults` set to `viewScoped` and a new `customResults` set to `requestScoped`.  This customResults, gets the info for my includes and works fine.  But when I click a listener within the page, all it does is call the constructor to the `customResults` and never the method `displayResults` method being called by the action.

Answer (score 1):

PreRenderView listeners are called within the RenderResponsePhase, before components are rendered BUT AFTER the TagHandlers are called. This means that TagHandlers will NOT see data initialized within a PreRenderView event.

If you are using a `<ui:include value="#{myBean.myViewId}" />` to dynamically switch an include you can't use a PreRenderView event listener to set the `myViewId` property of `myBean`.

If you need to do that use a `<f:phaseListener>`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  But as I understand and according to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct) I need to go through the `preRenderView` as the `myViewId` is dependent on the `viewParam` --> so I still need to "wait" till the update model values phase?

Comment: yes I would think so too but to believe it myself I would need to give it a try (stuff like this confuses me).