# usage of @ManagedProperty in prerender method

Tags: jsf, facelets, managed-property, prerenderview

I am having a data table like below in my xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable var="employee"
      value="#{employeeBean.employeeLazyDataModel}">
```

Now in my backing bean, I have:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty("#{" + EmployeeLazyDataModel.MANAGEDBEAN_NAME + "}")
    private EmployeeLazyDataModel employeeLazyDataModel;

    public void preRender(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws Exception {
        employeeLazyDataModel= // make a database call
    }

  // and getters + setters
```

Do you think I can call managedproperty inside preRender method?
Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Please first try if you can before you ask here

Comment: I did that and it is working. But I don't want to do all expensive operations inside preRender. And even if I move the stuffs to PostConstruct method, then also it will be called every time because we are in RequesScope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely this will work. The `@ManagedProperty` is injected *directly* after bean's construction. The `preRenderView` event listener requires an already-constructed bean before being invoked. So this is indeed guaranteed to work.

However, the canonical approach to initialize bean's state based on managed properties is a `@PostConstruct` annotated method. Thus, so:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty("#{" + EmployeeLazyDataModel.MANAGEDBEAN_NAME + "}")
    private EmployeeLazyDataModel employeeLazyDataModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        employeeLazyDataModel= // make a database call
    }

    // ...
}
```

*(don't forget to remove the `<f:event>` from the view)*

As to the "expensive operations" complaint in the comment, just put the bean in view scope if you don't want to run it on a per-request basis, but only once on a per-view basis.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable {
```

Note that the `preRenderView` event is fired before the view is rendered (thus, on every single HTTP request!), so you really need to keep the `@PostConstruct` here. Otherwise, you have to add a check if `FacesContext#isPostback()` returns `false`.

#### See also:

- [When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct/)
- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942/viewparam-vs-managedpropertyvalue-param-id/)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)