# JSF2.0 backing bean setter not invoked when using dataTable

Tags: jsf-2

I have a screen in which am using

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>

    <h:form>
    <f:event listener="#{pageload.getPageLoad}" type="preRenderView" />
    <h:dataTable value="#{pageload.fieldConfig}" var="field" 
    columnClasses="lblFirstCol,lblSecondCol,lblThirdCol,lblFourthCol" id="table1" styleClass="tblSecond" >
        <h:column >
        <h:outputText value="#{field.label_name}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>              
            <h:inputText value="#{searchdevice.device.terminal_name}" />
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable> 

    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{searchdevice.searchButtonAction}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And my backing bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="pageload")
@RequestScoped
public class PageLoadBean {

private List<FieldConfigVO> fieldconfig;
      //getters and setters

      // method  to populate the ArrayList
      public void getPageLoad(){
                   //getting populated from Database
         fieldconfig = common.getFieldConfig("001");        
      }  
  }
```

The other input bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="searchdevice")
@RequestScoped
 public class SearchDeviceBean {

private DeviceVO device;




public SearchDeviceBean() {
    device = new DeviceVO();
}

public DeviceVO getDevice() {
    return device;
}

public void setDevice(DeviceVO device) {
    this.device = device;
}

public String searchButtonAction(){
    System.out.println(device.getTerminal_name()+"****TERMINAL NAME******");
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (context.getMessageList().size() > 0) {
        return(null);
    }else {

        return("success");
    }

}
     }
```

My Device Object has the terminal_name property.I have a command button which invokes method in SearchDeviceBean and on submitting the form whatever value I enter doesn't get populated

Any help appreciated

Comment: are you using h:commadButton if yes then are you calling it from a h:form or not. if this does not solve your problem please post complete page info

Comment: Please provide your entire form code and your `SearchDeviceBean` class code.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). Otherwise it's unlikely you'll get help, as there are too many places where the mistake could be.

Comment: yes I using commandButton .My full code is

Comment: It is working if I  make  my backing bean SessionScoped.Not working in RequestScoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing data initialization logic in `preRenderView` event. This is the wrong place for code which needs to prepare the model for the postback. When JSF needs to update the model values during form submit, it is encountering a completely empty `fieldConfig` and therefore JSF can't set the submitted/converted/validated values in there. The `fieldConfig` is in your case only prepared during a later phase, the render response phase, which is thus too late.

You need to initialize it in `@PostConstruct` instead. It's invoked immediately after bean's construction and dependency in jection. Get rid of the whole `<f:event>` altogether and put a `@PostConstruct` annotation on the `getPageLoad()` method. I'd by the way also rename that method to `init()` or `loadFieldConfig()` as it isn't a getter method at all and therefore a very confusing name to other people reading/maintaining your code.

#### See also:

- [When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct/)

Comment: Thanku @BalusC I now understood the difference and it is working fine for me now