# Clicking on commandLink is invoking preRenderView again

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, commandlink, prerenderview

In my facelet, I have the below commandLink:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandLink id="excelExport" action="#{studentBean.exportReport()}" ajax="false">
         <f:param name="type" value="EXCEL" />
         <p:graphicImage library="img" name="excel.png" width="20" />
    </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

This is what I am having in my backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class StudentBean implements Serializable {
    .............
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.type}")
    private String typeOfExport;

    .............
    public void preRender(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Inside prerender");
        if (FacesHelper.isAjaxRequest()) {
            return;
        }
    }
    .............
    public void exportReport() {
        System.out.println("Type of Report is: " + typeOfExport);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to execute the method exportReport once I click on the commandLink. But what is happening here is that after executing the method, it is going to preRender again. I don't want to render the entire form again. Any idea what mistake I am doing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [preRenderView is called on every ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974950/prerenderview-is-called-on-every-ajax-request)

Comment: By the way ... `<h:commandLink>` doesn't support `ajax` attribute. Perhaps you mixed it with `<p:commandLink>`?

Comment: If you are going to use `<p:commandLink>` be aware of the attributes you need to use. Please check commandLink Primefaces Showcase [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandLink.jsf) to understand what I am talking about.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes you are correct. I edited the question. And I removed the ajax part. Now I realized the difference between ajax="true" and ajax="false" with RequestBean. Thanks a lot

Comment: with ajax="false" the page refreshes and preRender should be called again.