# JSF call a bean method before the page load

Tags: jsf

I have to call a init method on my bean as first action on the page load, I have tried to simply call `#{bean.init}` at the very beginning of my page, but I have seen that the `<c:if>` tests are performed before the `init()`. I have something like

```
#{bean.init}
<c:if test="#{bean.conditionsCheck}">...</c:if>
```

and the `conditionsCheck()` method is called before the `init()`,
how can I fix it and call `init()` as really first thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation to automatically invoke your init method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
  // do something
}
```

This method is automatically invoked after construction of the bean.

Your solution looks more like a `f:event` with `type="preRenderView"` but this can't be used because the `c:if` tags are evaluated during view build time, while the `f:event` (respectively your solution) runs right before the view is rendered during render response phase. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) to get details.

**Update:** As you commented you are using a `@SessionScoped` bean where `@PostConstruct` is only called once per session and not on every page load. In this case another solution would be to call your `init` method as first statement in your `conditionsCheck` method (nearly the same as your suggestion with fake `c:if` boolean init). You could also use a custom `PhaseListener` but I guess that would be somewhat overdosed for this problem.

See also:

- [Why use @PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406555/why-use-postconstruct)

Comment: As described in the question he is using a simple EL call to invoke the method. Anyway, shouldn't the @PostConstruct fix the problem?

Comment: Indeed, but `preRenderView` won't solve the problem. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984/

Comment: I don't know if @PostConstruct will solve the problem, but it will introduce another problem, for SessionScoped it runs only after the initialization of the bean, not every time that I reload a page

Comment: I will solve the problem using a "fake" c:if testing a "Boolean init()"

Answer (score 0):

This works if you add a JSF Control like `CommandButton`, and in its value you write it as:

`value="#{sessionScopedBean.method()}"`

This method will be called whenever this page loads.

Answer (score -1):

for anyone searching ...

We can use preRender of scriptCollector tag, if the used JSF implementation supports it, something like:

```
<scriptCollector id="scriptCollector1" preRender="#{bean.method}">
...
</scriptCollector>
```