# JSF 2.2: viewAction triggers earlier than actionListener and action

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have been using preRenderView (+ the re-direct and skip postback hacks) in my app and I'm trying to replace it with viewAction that comes with JSF2.2 (MyFaces 2.2.4).  However I found it triggers earlier than command actionListener and action that it's rather useless for my purpose.  For example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean2 implements Serializable {

  int count = 0;

  public void actionFunc() {
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  public String addCount() {
    count++;
    return null;
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return count;
  }

  public void initView() {
    System.out.println("initView");
  }

  public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
  }

}
```

and then a very simple .xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
  xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{testBean2.initView}" />
  <f:viewAction action="#{testBean2.actionFunc}" onPostback="true" />
</f:metadata>

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="title">Test</ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
    #{testBean2.count}
        <h:form>
      <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary" action="#{testBean2.addCount}" value="addCount">
      </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

So the addCount() System.out output is always 1 behind what's on the rendered view, because actionFunc() always triggers before addCount().

If I want to do something like, if (count == 3) do a return "newpage" for a redirect, it ends up way too early for such decision.  I can do the check in initView() and do ConfigurableNavigationHandler.performNavigation("newpage"), but that's the kind of hack I'm trying to eliminate with JSF 2.2.

Therefore, it seems like viewAction is rather useless if I want it to work with any value that I'm going to change with action or actionListener.  Is it supposed to work like this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question sounds interesting, have you read in the [docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsf22-1377252.html) about the `f:viewAction` tag? There are other attributes such as `phase` or `immediate`, give them a try and don't forget to publish an answer if you happen to achieve it!

Comment: Hi.  Already tried.  phase by default is already at the latest possible: "APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES, PROCESS_VALIDATIONS, UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES, or INVOKE_APPLICATION. The default is INVOKE_APPLICATION."  immediate="true" makes it APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES, which is even earlier what it is now.

Comment: I began writing a comment, but I ended up writing a whole answer with the way I think it's intended to work. Hope it'll be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

`preRenderView` event [is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9844616/1199132) at the beginning of the *RENDER_RESPONSE* phase. However, the `viewAction` tag does not allow that phase. I suppose that in your case you should handle the redirection in your action method (`TestBean2#addCount`) and forget about using events, cause it makes no sense at all to perform a check over a value that has been just initialized (that's what you do with the `preRenderView` method, when you load the view at first time). Checking it into the action method, after having performed your logic, seems the natural way for it.

I believe events can be used to check conditions as well, but they have more to do with session and application states and not with your current view values. I mean, you could do this to handle a redirection when no items available in your shop, before your view gets rendered:

```
public String checkItemsAvailable() {
    if (!dao.itemsAvailable()){
        return "noItemsAvailable";
    }
    return null;
}
```

But for a redirection based in a condition that's being evaluated in your current view, performing it in the action method is the best way to go:

```
public void addCount() {
    count++;
    if (count>3){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [`f:viewAction` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewAction.html)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the answer.

In the actual case, the action method actually lives inside of a SessionScoped bean and changes a value within it (say, a mode A/B toggle) and returns to the same view (it always return null).  My intention is to have the viewAction in each page to check that, and do things accordingly (like, redirect).  Therefore, I can't hard-code a non-null return in the action method.

With what it is now, the viewAction method always sees that value 1-step behind compared to what preRenderView sess, which is the correct value.

Comment: Also, further testing shows if the action goes to a different view, then viewAction is triggered after the action.  However if the action goes back to the same view (i.e., return null;), viewAction (again, with postback=true) triggers BEFORE the action.

Comment: I don't know what your concrete case is, however, having seen the viewaction documentation, I infer you can use it to redirect based in conditions that were set before current request. If you want to redirect basing in current request, use a redirection inside your current button methods. Anyway, you always have the choice of keeping as you were doing with prerenderview.

Comment: @JPlatinum, your second comment makes sense if the different view you're going to has a `viewAction` tag too. But that's just because it's another JSF cycle what you are performing (the `viewAction` in the destination view will be called after first view's action).