# Call session scoped bean method on every view

Tags: jsf-2, view, session-scope, postconstruct

Perhaps this is a question I should be able to find documentation on, but I'm unfamiliar with a lot of the jargon so I'm struggling.

Basically, I'm using JSF2.  I have a SessionScoped bean, and it uses a postconstruct init() method.  I want the init() method to be called everytime the session starts, which works fine, but I also want it to be called every time the view loads.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `@PostConstruct` by `<f:event type="preRenderView">`.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{sessionScopedBean.init}" />
```

Better, however, is to split it into 2 beans: a `@SessionScoped` one and a `@ViewScoped` one. Then just reference the `@ViewScoped` one in the view instead and inject the `@SessionScoped` one as a property of the `@ViewScoped` one.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ViewScopedBean {

    @Inject
    private SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)

Comment: Perfect thank you!  And in case anyone is curious about this someone just found me this resource which is very useful ... http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Part-5