# JSF viewParam not set

Tags: jsf

xhtml file I use a viewParam:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="actionId" value="#{editActionView.actionId}" required="true" />
</f:metadata>           
<h:body>
```

The backing bean looks as follows:

**EditActionView.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EditActionView {
    private long actionId;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        System.out.println("actionId: " + getActionId());
    }


    public long getActionId() {
        return actionId;
    }

    public void setActionId(long actionId) {
        this.actionId = actionId;
    }
```

When I now call my application:

```
http://localhost:8080/aip/editAction.jsf?actionId=37
```

actionId is always 0. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 2):

The ManagedBean is constructed before the setter is called. Therefore the System.out.println(...) in the @PostConstruct method prints the default value for the actionId of type long which is 0.
The setter is then called in the UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES phase. You can check this by putting another System.out.println(...) in the setter method, which should print the correct value.

Comment: hm... I want to initialize my backing-bean based on a GET Paramter. How would I then retrieve the value?

Comment: Here is a good answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-fviewaction-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-fviewaction-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct) . In summary: You can use a `<f:viewAction>` (since JSF 2.2) or a `<f:event type="preRenderView">` (JSF 2.0, 2.1)