# bootsfaces inputTest using f:ajax unexpected calling bean method from f:viewAction

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I have two managed beans `NavigationState` and `ClientManager`both are viewScope.

`NavigationState`has the `getContentPage()` method that is referenced on the viewAction:

```
<c:metadata>
    <c:viewAction action="#{navState.init('client', 'clientDetails')}"/>
</c:metadata>
```

`ClientManager`has the `searchingClients` method that is referenced on the bootsfaces `inputText`

```
 <b:inputText placeholder="nome" id="name"
                value="#{clientManager.clientOnSearch.firstName}"
                style="background: rgb(251, 251, 251) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);">
            <c:ajax execute="name" event="keyup" 
            listener="#{clientManager.searchingClients()}" />       
            </b:inputText>
```

When I type a key on this input text field the only method called is the `getContentPage()` from the `NavigationState`and not the `searchingClients()` from `clientManager`

Any idea why this is happening ?

Thank you

Bruno

Comment: getContentPage()? Your metadata section doesn't mention getContentPage(). Maybe a typo?

Comment: I'm not an expert with these f:ajax facets - but shouldn't it be `listener="#{clientManager.searchingClients}` (without parentheses)?

Comment: since bootsfaces key events attrs are not working fine I won't use this one. thanks

Comment: @b.lopes Did you check your question and the snippet code again, after Stephan's comment? It looks a bit odd, that you're referring to `navState.getContentPage()` , if the viewAction itself only uses `navState.init`. Is it a typo or intended?

Comment: Using different XML namespace prefixes than documented is genuinely confusing. The `c` prefix is documented for JSTL core tags, not JSF core tags. Try to not deviate from the standards.

Answer (score 0):

#### Usage of `viewAction`

First things first, check if you really need to use a `viewAction`, you may as well just use a simple `@PostConstruct` in your backing bean instead. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9844616/1644440) if you want to learn more about the differences.)

At the moment it looks like the viewAction is fired on every GET requests. However I'm not familiar with `viewAction`s internal, maybe your backing bean is request scoped and therefore gets initialized on every ajax request?

It may help, if you get rid of it. If you don't need `viewParam`s, just use `@PostConstruct` instead.

#### Ajax with BootsFaces

How does your `clientManager.searchingClients()` method's signature look like?
If it looks like `clientManager.searchingClients(AjaxBehaviorEvent e)`, using  parantheses won't work, you must opt for `clientManager.searchingClients` then.

Otherwise I don't see any errors in your JSF markup, it's exactly as in the  [showcase's first example](http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/inputText.jsf).

However, I never really used `f:ajax` (or `c:ajax` in your case). It's always a bit quirky. But you also don't have to: In case of PrimeFaces there's `p:ajax` and in case of `BootsFaces` [we got our own recommended way of invoking ajax listeners](http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/ajax.jsf).

So maybe you want to give this a try:

```
 <b:inputText placeholder="nome" id="name"
     value="#{clientManager.clientOnSearch.firstName}"
     style="background: rgb(251, 251, 251) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);"
     onkeyup="ajax:clientManager.searchingClients()"/>
```

While trying the current 0.8.1 Showcase I found, that the InputText ajax example didn't quite work, so I will investigate, if this is caused by 0.8.1 or an old version of the showcase. It works in the [Snapshot Showcase](http://www3.bootsfaces.net/Showcase/forms/inputText.jsf) though.