# embeding java cookie to html

Tags: java, html, jsf, cookies

hello guys i am working on a java web page, i have all my classes and xhtml files.
i can create the cookies but i can't check them when the page is loaded. i have a get cookie function which is:

```
public Cookie getCookie(String name)
```

it returns null if there is no cookie, i am trying to write

```
if(user.getCookie==null)
goto login.xhtml
```

basically that's what i am trying to do. how can i embed this code into html file?

and in my logout, how can i remove all the cookies?

Comment: which jsf version you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JSF 2.x. you can use  [PreRenderView](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PreRenderViewEvent.html)  tag to execute a method before the page is loaded in JSF to check that if the user cookie is not null before rendering the page . The preRenderView event is invoked on every HTTP request.
You can make use of the PreRenderViewEvent like below :

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{cookiesChecker.check}" />
</f:metadata>
```

And here is the listener

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped 
public class cookiesChecker{

    public void check() {
       if(user.getCookie==null)
       goto login.xhtml
    }

    // ...
}
```

**More Info :**

[When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-fviewaction-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct?lq=1)