# composite's method is called before preRenderView

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2 .xhtml page which looks like this:

```
<h:body>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{view.init}" />
  <customComponents:mytable />
</h:body>
```

And the composite implementation

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="tableForm">
      <ui:repeat value="#{view.actions}" var="action">
      <h:outputText value="#{action.start}">
        <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{view.timeZone}" />
      </h:outputText>
    </h:form>
</composite>
```

Now when I load the view the composite's `#{view.timeZone}` is called BEFORE `listener={view.init}`

I don't get this. I want the `init` message called before the getter is called. Can you tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

`preRenderView` has to be in `f:metadata` tag. For example:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{view.init}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

FYI, this post can help you too [When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9844526/4605161)

Comment: not sure it is because of `f:metadata` because the method is called, however I am not sure about the order

Comment: It's probably been called during build time, that's why

Comment: can I execute the init method before build time?

Comment: `getTimeZone` is a simple getter or it does more than that? If it's more than that, you should be more careful, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: it is a simple getter