# JSF2 AJAX h:selectOneMenu listener doesn't call

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I try to make 2 h:selectOneMenu component on the page. When I choose some subject from the first selectOneMenu I want to use ajax with listener where I get id selected subject and fill list tests for this subject in other selectOneMenu. I use bean with session scoped.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{test.getAllSubjects}" />
<h:form prependId="false">          
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty test.testBean.subjectList}">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{test.testBean.subjectId}" id="subjects">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select a subject--" itemValue="0" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{test.testBean.subjectList}"
                            var="subjectItem" itemValue="#{subjectItem.subjectId}"
                            itemLabel="#{subjectItem.subject}" />
                        <f:ajax event="change" render="tests" listener="#{test.testsBySubjectId}" />                
                    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{test.testBean.test.testIdentifer.testId}" id="tests">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select a test--" itemValue="0" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{test.testBean.testList}" var="testItem" 
                        itemValue="#{testItem.testIdentifer.testId}" itemLabel="#{testItem.testName}" />                                    
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

And in managed bean Use next listener

```
public void getTestsBySubjectId() throws DAOException {
     Long subjectId = testBean.getSubjectId();
     List<Test> testList = testBo.getTestBySubjectId(subjectId);
     testBean.setTestList(testList);
     }
```

But this listener will never be called.

That's why I made some tricks I change  tag as `<f:ajax event="change" render="tests" />` without listener.

But in `h:selectOneMenu` for test I did

```
<f:selectItems value="#{test.testsBySubjectId}" var="testItem"
                        itemValue="#{testItem.testIdentifer.testId}"
                        itemLabel="#{testItem.testName}" />
```

And there I initialize value not values tests from bean test list. I try to init as

```
public List<Test> getTestsBySubjectId() throws DAOException {
        Long subjectId = testBean.getSubjectId();
        List<Test> testList = testBo.getTestBySubjectId(subjectId);
        testBean.setTestList(testList);
        return testList;
    }
```

This variant works. But I don't understand why previous variant with listener doesn't work.

Where is my fault? And what should be changed for right result?

Comment: Is that inside an `<h:form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SJuan76 You are right. With name of listener but I understand my real problem.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{test.getAllSubjects}" />
```

This listener calls on ajax postback. I understand this from this article.[Is it possible to disable f:event type=“preRenderView” listener on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506033/is-it-possible-to-disable-fevent-type-prerenderview-listener-on-postback)

Thanks @BalusC

And I also add arg `AjaxBehaviorEvent event`in listener method

Answer (score 3):

The listener is not a property. If you method in the java bean is `getTestBySubjectId()`, put it like that (brackets are not needed) in the attribute.

```
 <f:ajax event="change" render="tests" listener="#{test.getTestsBySubjectId}" />
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When I choose subject again will call `getAllSubjects` from bean which called from `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{test.getAllSubjects}" />` that situated outside `<h:form>`

Comment: I add in question text above form and `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{test.getAllSubjects}" />`

Comment: Even If I put '<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{test.getAllSubjects}" />' inside `<h:form>` it'll be called every time when call ajax request

Comment: Could you delete the `throws` clause? I can't find a reference right now, but none of the methods signatures for listeners that I am used to throws an Exception (I think it can throw an `javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException`).