# Exception during bean's @PostConstruct does not end up in right <error-page>

Tags: jsf, exception, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, postconstruct

My question is quite simple (to ask). How can I create and manage my Exceptions in a JSF application?

First we have the separation from normal and Ajax requests.
Problem solved by using [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) by Omnifaces.

Ok, now my Ajax exceptions follow the JSF/`web.xml` path. Next step is to create the mappings in `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.SecurityException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/security.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

The problem then is that Exceptions are not going to match above rules as they have been wrapped by other Exception types.
Ok, Omnifaces to the rescue again with [FacesExceptionFilter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/filters/FacesExceptionFilter).

Ok, so now I can throw Exceptions from my beans, e.g.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    throw new SecurityException("Go away!");
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work, because Exception is thrown during bean initialization and not when calling a method.

Omnifaces `unwrap` method will stop to the occurrence of  a`FacesException` and CDI (Weld) will wrap any exceptions during `Bean` initialization to a FacesException (which I assume is conforming to the spec).

I could write my own Exception filter that will not stop unwrapping a `FacesException`, you quickly realize that you might go deeper in the stacktrace than one would like.

How can I manage Exceptions during `Bean` initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The managed bean creation and initialization is not supposed to throw an exception in first place.

You'd better move this security checking logic elsewhere. E.g. a real security framework (container managed via JAAS/JASPIC or 3rd party like Shiro), or a servlet filter, or if you 
really really want to keep it in "the JSF house", use `<f:viewAction>` instead.

```html
<f:viewAction action="#{bean.init}" />
```

*(don't forget to remove the `@PostConstruct` annotation)*

If you're not on JSF 2.2 yet, use `preRenderView` event instead.

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/)
- [Is it possible to disable f:event type="preRenderView" listener on postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506033/is-it-possible-to-disable-fevent-type-prerenderview-listener-on-postback)

Comment: The actual authentication is handled inside a filter, but the resource authorization happens in the bean. The bean will try to verify that the authenticated user has access to the specific resource.This is difficult to move to a filter. The preRenderView  would work on a Request scoped bean, but in a @Viewscoped bean like the one I have will run init more than once right? I could get around this by having a bool to make sure it runs only once, but the logic becomes ugly.I considered extending your filter by also checking if the exception comes from CDI,but then again portability will be lost

Comment: `preRenderView` runs regardless of bean scope on every request, also on postbacks. But I now realized that you're using JSF 2.2, you'd better use `<f:viewAction>` instead. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and reply. What i meant is that request scope bean init matches the lifecycle of prerenderview (initialized on every request/postback where a viewscoped only initialized on init request). I'll have a look on the frameworks you suggested