# Update a datatable after a selection in another datatable

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable that needs to update another datatable when the user select a row. The resultSelectedCommunity object is correctly being updated after the selection event, but the content of the second datatable is not refreshing. I checked in the browser and apparently the update class (:formFreq:tableFreq) is correct. I know that are some related issues posted here, but I read each one of those and none of the solutions worked for me. I am using Primefaces 5.1 and JSF 2.2.9.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{results.loadComponents}" ></f:event>
</f:metadata>
...
<h:body>
...

<h:form id="formResults">           
    <p:dataTable id="tableComm" value="#{results.communitiesList}" var="community" selectionMode="single" selection="#{results.resultSelectedCommunity}" rowKey="#{community.id}">
        <f:facet name="header">
        Communities
        </f:facet>
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{results.onResultsCommSelect}" update=":formFreq:tableFreq" />
        <p:column>
            #{community.toString()} [#{community.size()}]
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<h:form id="formFreq">  
    <p:dataTable id="tableFreq" value="#{results.resultSelectedCommunity.nodes}" var="node" rowIndexVar="index">>
        <f:facet name="header">
            Frequencies
        </f:facet>
        <p:column>
            <b>#{node}</b>
        </p:column>

        <p:columns value="#{results.resultSelectedCommunity.columnHeaders}" var="col" columnIndexVar="colIndex">
            <f:facet name="header">
                #{col}
            </f:facet>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{results.resultSelectedCommunity.getFrequenceRow(node).get(colIndex)}" styleClass="#{results.resultSelectedCommunity.getColumnColorStatus(node,colIndex)}"/>
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Im adding a print just to clarify my problem. The user should click on the left item and the table should update its content. It is a very simple task, I have a lot of update routines on my project, but for some reason that I cant figure out, this is one is not working.

[image]
*This ajax submit button should not exist. I just add it to make some tests

Thanks

Comment: You should make a trigger will be much easier to solve this problem in the database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Im not using a database, it should be a very simple task, but I'm testing it for hours and still cant figure out the problem. I add a print to clarify what I am trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure the content of `#{results.resultSelectedCommunity.nodes}` changed when `"#{results.onResultsCommSelect}` is called? [mcve] please with static data (no db stuff)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Im going to make a minimal verifable example. I think I figured out what's causing the problem. I have a preRenderComponent that initialize my objects when the page is first load. It might being called again in the ajax update routine, but I still dont know how to fix it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506033/is-it-possible-to-disable-fevent-type-prerenderview-listener-on-postback. Next time make an [mcve] before posting. It helps you narrow down the problem upfront!

Comment: Thank you very much Kukeltje, you solve my problem. I just had to add an if statement checking if it is a postback. Next time I will post a minimal executable example before posting.